# How do I add a filter to a checkbox list in a content editing form

Tags: 7, entities

I have a taxonomy select field within a node form (7). I've chosen checkboxes and it is hard to scan them. I'd like to be able to add a filter so that the user can enter text to limit the number of choices in the list. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 8 the best way to create an advanced ER field widget is with the help of the [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) module.

You will have to create the Entity browsers for your Taxonomy terms, and use Views Widget plugin to create the final browser that has the exposed filter: [Views | Widgets](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/entity-browser/widgets#views)

You can also find tutorials about how to set up your own Entity Browser, usually they describe how to build a Media gallery, but you can follow a lot of the steps from those to create the taxonomy term case you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `Reference method` option in your Field settings to `Views: Filter by an entity reference view`.

You first have to build the Views listing taxonomy terms, Display of type Entity Reference. Add the exposed filter there for the term name. Save the View.

Then you'll be able to select that ER Views Display in your Field settings.

Comment: I setup my entity reference + view with exposed filter. I got my checkbox list but no exposed filter.

Comment: Correct! I'm so sorry, I remembered creating a solution like this but it was in D7 and with the help of [Entity Reference View Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) module. In D8 you need the Entity Browser.

Answer (score 0):

In d7 achieved this by laying out the options as checkboxes and filtering with javascript. With d8 the entity browser is great if slow.

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document) {
  'use strict';

   Drupal.behaviors.filterwebinars = {
     attach: function (context, settings) {
     if ($("#edit-field-event-sponsors").length) {
     $("<label for=\"filter-event-sponsors\">Filter Sponsors</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"filter-event-sponsors\" name=\"filter-event-sponsors\" id=\"filter-field-event-sponsors\"\/>").prependTo('#edit-field-event-sponsors');
     $('#filter-field-event-sponsors').keyup(function(){
      let filterText = $('#filter-field-event-sponsors').val().toLowerCase();
      let filter = $("#edit-field-event-sponsors-und :checkbox").filter(function() {
        if (this.labels[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(filterText)){
            $(this).parent().show();
              return this.value;
            }
            $.(this).parent().hide();
            return false;
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```